# Why autoencoder is not learning?

Tags: python, autoencoder, machine-learning-model

The loss function is MSE which is not decreasing (2.32 to 2.24). What is the problem AE architecture or the way I train the AE? After 100 epochs the loss doesn't change. Is the input data(200,1,52) can't be compressed? Should I increase the compressed data size(200,16) by changing the encoder architecture?

[image: Training Loss curve]

```
# Standard Torch Packages
import torch
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from torch.nn import functional as F
from torch import optim
from os.path import join, exists
from os import mkdir
import numpy as np
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Import own functions
from ae_model import AE
from learning import EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau, LSIZE

# Define parameters
num_epochs = 50
rollout_path = "data/rollouts/rollout_*.npz"
logdir = "data/"

X = []
for x in glob.glob(rollout_path):
    data_point = np.load(x, allow_pickle=True)
    X.append(data_point)

train_loader, test_loader = train_test_split(X, test_size=0.2, shuffle= False)
cuda = torch.cuda.is_available()
device = torch.device("cuda" if cuda else "cpu")
print(device)

model = AE(LSIZE).to(device)
#optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters())
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(),
                             lr = 1e-1,
                             weight_decay = 1e-8)
scheduler = ReduceLROnPlateau(optimizer, "min", factor=0.5, patience=5)
earlystopping = EarlyStopping("min", patience=3)

# Validation using MSE Loss function
loss_function = torch.nn.MSELoss()

def train(epoch):
    """ One training epoch """
    model.train()
    train_loss = []
    #train_data_points = 0
    for batch_idx, rollout in enumerate(train_loader):
        data = torch.tensor(rollout["data"]).to(device)
        train_data_points = len(data) * len(train_loader)
        #recon_batch, mu, logvar = model(data)
        recon_batch, _ = model(data)
        loss = loss_function(recon_batch, data)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        #train_loss += loss.item()
        optimizer.step()
        plot_train_data.append(loss.item())

    #     if batch_idx % 20 == 0:
    #         print(
    #             "Train Epoch: {} [{}/{} ({:.0f}%)]\tLoss: {:.6f}".format(
    #                 epoch,
    #                 batch_idx * len(data),
    #                 train_data_points,
    #                 100.0 * batch_idx / len(train_loader),
    #                 loss.item() / len(data),
    #             )
    #         )
    # train_loss /= train_data_points
    # print(
    #     "====> Epoch: {} Average loss: {:.4f}".format(
    #         epoch, train_loss / train_data_points
    #     )
        print(
        "====> Epoch: {} batchId: {} Average loss: {:.4f}".format(
            epoch, batch_idx, loss.item()
        ))
    # )

    return train_loss

def test():
    model.eval()
    test_loss = 0
    test_data_points = 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for rollout in test_loader:
            data = torch.tensor(rollout["data"]).to(device)
            test_data_points = len(data) * len(test_loader)
            #recon_batch, mu, logvar = model(data)
            recon_batch, _ = model(data)
            test_loss += loss_function(recon_batch, data).item()

    test_loss /= test_data_points
    print("====> Test set loss: {:.4f}".format(test_loss))
    return test_loss


def save_checkpoint(state, is_best, filename, best_filename):
    """ Save state in filename. Also save in best_filename if is_best. """
    torch.save(state, filename)
    if is_best:
        torch.save(state, best_filename)


# check vae dir exists, if not, create it
ae_dir = join(logdir, "ae_gpu_run_false")
if not exists(ae_dir):
    mkdir(ae_dir)

reload_file = join(ae_dir, "best.tar")
noreload = False

if not noreload and exists(reload_file):
    state = torch.load(reload_file)
    print(
        "Reloading model at epoch {}"
        ", with test error {}".format(state["epoch"], state["precision"])
    )
    model.load_state_dict(state["state_dict"])
    optimizer.load_state_dict(state["optimizer"])
    scheduler.load_state_dict(state["scheduler"])
    earlystopping.load_state_dict(state["earlystopping"])

cur_best = None
plot_train_data = []
plot_test_data = []

for epoch in range(1, num_epochs + 1):
    
    #plot_train_data.append(train(epoch))
    train(epoch)
    test_loss = test()
    scheduler.step(test_loss)
    earlystopping.step(test_loss)

    # checkpointing
    best_filename = join(ae_dir, "best.tar")
    filename = join(ae_dir, "checkpoint.tar")
    is_best = not cur_best or test_loss < cur_best
    if is_best:
        cur_best = test_loss

    save_checkpoint(
        {
            "epoch": epoch,
            "state_dict": model.state_dict(),
            "precision": test_loss,
            "optimizer": optimizer.state_dict(),
            "scheduler": scheduler.state_dict(),
            "earlystopping": earlystopping.state_dict(),
        },
        is_best,
        filename,
        best_filename,
    )

    if earlystopping.stop:
        print("End of Training because of early stopping at epoch {}".format(epoch))
        break

test_plot_path = join(ae_dir, "test_fig.png")
# legend_strings = []
plt.title("AE Training and Test")
#plt.xlabel("Epochs")
#plt.ylabel("MSE losses")
#plt.plot(plot_test_data)
# legend_strings.append('Test')
#plt.legend('Test')
#plt.savefig(test_plot_path)
#plt.close()

#train_plot_path = join(ae_dir, "train_fig.png")
#plt.title("AE ")
#plt.xlabel("Epochs")
#plt.ylabel("MSE Loss")
plt.plot(plot_train_data)
# legend_strings.append('Train')
#plt.legend('Train')
plt.xticks(range(0, len(plot_train_data), 75))
plt.savefig(test_plot_path)
plt.close()
```

Below is the encoder and decoder model:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

reduced_size = 22


class Decoder(nn.Module):
    """ VAE decoder """

    def __init__(self, latent_size):
        super(Decoder, self).__init__()
        self.latent_size = latent_size
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(latent_size, reduced_size)
        self.deconv1 = nn.ConvTranspose1d(16, 32, 1, stride=1)
        self.deconv2 = nn.ConvTranspose1d(32, 52, 1, stride=1)

    def forward(self, x):  # pylint: disable=arguments-differ
        x = x.unsqueeze(2)
        x = F.relu(self.deconv1(x))
        x = torch.sigmoid(self.deconv2(x))
        x = x.view(x.size(0), x.size(2), x.size(1))
        return x


class Encoder(nn.Module):  # pylint: disable=too-many-instance-attributes
    """ VAE encoder """

    def __init__(self, latent_size):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__()
        # input shape (200, 1, 52)
        # batch_size, in_channel, len_channel
        self.latent_size = latent_size
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(52, 32, 1, stride=1)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv1d(32, 16, 1, stride=1)
        # output shape (200, 1, x)
        self.fc_mu = nn.Linear(reduced_size, latent_size)

    def forward(self, x):  # pylint: disable=arguments-differ
        x = x.view(x.size(0), x.size(2), x.size(1))
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv2(x))
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        return x


class AE(nn.Module):
    """ Variational Autoencoder """

    def __init__(self, latent_size):
        super(AE, self).__init__()
        self.encoder = Encoder(latent_size)
        self.decoder = Decoder(latent_size)

    def forward(self, x):  # pylint: disable=arguments-differ
        x = x.unsqueeze(1)
        encoded = self.encoder(x)
        decoded = self.decoder(encoded)
        decoded = decoded.squeeze(1)

        return decoded, encoded
```